# How do I create a summation series in a HighStock chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a HighStock chart which is displaying multiple data series.  Along with those data series I would like to also display a series which is the total of all the data series for every data point.

All this would look like is another line that represents the summation of data at each point on the x axis.  Does anyone know how I could easily do this using the HighStock API?

I currently just create a totals data series before initializing the chart and include in as one of the series in the dataset that I assign to HighStocks.  I would however like to make this dynamic.

Comment: I am just going to continue creating the total series before creating the chart for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use dataLabels formatter http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.area.dataLabels.formatter which allows to define own function. So you should calculate sum by addig each point form serie with defined x value.

Comment: I had a look at the docs and can't really figure out how I would create a brand new series with the totals by putting a custom function in the datalabels.Formatter attribute.